# How can I escape arguments passed in bash script command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have one variable, which is coming from some where like:

```
VAR1='hhgfhfghhgf"";2Ddgfsaj!!!$#^$\'&%*%~*)_)(_{}||\\/'
```

Now i have command like this

```
./myscript.sh '$VAR1'
```

I am getting that $VAR1 from some diff process and when I display it look exactly as its above.

Now that command is failing as there is already single quote inside variable. In the process where I use it it is expanded at that point, which causes that error.

I have control over myscript.sh but not above command.

Is there any way I can get variable inside my script?

Comment: Variables in `bash` don't take a space on either side of `=`. It shouldn't be `var = 1` but `var=1`

Comment: @Inian Plus the variable on the left side is written without the dollar sign. That said, I 'm curious about answers.

Comment: `./myscript.sh '$VAR1'` can't fail by itself because the variable is not being expanded.

Comment: @thatotherguy I am getting that $VAR1 from some diff process and when i display it look excatly as its above , in the process wehre i use its expaned at that point , which causes that error

Comment: Did someone mess up an `eval` statement? Please include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the error

Comment: How do you start the script? On the terminal, or thru some program? You might find quoting routines like [g_shell_quote](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Shell-related-Utilities.html#g-shell-quote)

Comment: @Master : Please be more precise in your question. There is nothing syntactically incorrect in the two statements you presented here, so if anything is possibly failing, it must be during the evaluation of `myscript.sh`, but since we don't know what is inside this script, we can not tell what's going wrong. Asider from this, the whole concept of passing the string `$VAR` to the script (instead of the content of the variable `VAR` looks odd to me, but you will probably know what you are doing here....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are saying is not possible to failing when passing to your script. Might your `script` has processing issue (or a command where this argument will passing into it) which cannot expand the variable correctly. You can either use `printf` with `%q` modifier to escape all special characters then pass it to your script:

```
./myscript.sh "$(printf '%q\n' "$VAR1")"
```

... or do the same within your script before you wanted to pass to some other commands:

```
VAR2="$(printf '%q\n' "$VAR1")"
```